# Discord disconnect when on Cisco VPN (Multi-protocol VPN client (openconnect))

Tags: fedora, cisco, openconnect, discord

i would like to ask for advice. I have Fedora 38 and I am also using Discord there. Problem is, that anytime I connect to VPN (which I need for work), discord disconnects. I have tried to completely turn off firewalld for a while, I tried to change dns to 8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4, but nothing helps. When I am on Windows 11 and connected to cisco vpn, I cannot start Discord app, but if its running before connecting to VPN, its ok and it stays connected, so I can use it for communication without any issues.

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: A VPN service would likely be setting/altering your network routing.  Showing your routing information (`ip route`) both before you connect to VPN and after you connect the VPN might shed some light on your issue.  Some corporate VPNs will want to route all of your default traffic through the VPN, and that could allow them to prevent some connections from working.

Comment: Thank you. Finally I found out, that if I turn on proxy in network settings, it works well and discord is not disconnecting anymore